# "Thunderstorm" vs. "tempest" in common usage

Tags: etymology, expressions, history

When did "thunderstorm" replace "tempest" in common English usage?

I ask the question because my great-great grandmother, who lived in South Weymouth, Massachusetts, used the term frequently in her dairy of the year 1905.

Comment: [1978](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tempest%2C+thunderstorm&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: Until [2003](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tempest%2Cthunderstorm&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: @MattЭллен Is this US usage? Going back to the 1950s, I've never heard a thunderstorm called a tempest in the UK. Also, I would associate 'tempest' with wind, not with thunder - as borne out [here](http://http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=tempest&title=21s) and [here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tempest?q=tempest).

Comment: @TrevorD It was meant as a joke :D Although the Google ngrams "English", in theory, encompasses all dialects.

Comment: @MattЭллен OK - sorry, I hadn't appreciated that. (I had looked at your profile and couldn't work out from your location - altho' I thought it maybe in northern Britain, I wasn't sure. But now I've noticed your website tld, it's obvious!

Comment: @MattЭллен, note that ngrams document written word. For oral tradition there should be some other source. As for corpus, yes, ngrams by default include all variations, but one can specify to search British or American corpuses directly.

Comment: @MattЭллен If you take the 3 year boxcar smooth off the ngram plot, you'll see that thunderstorm usage briefly eclipsed use of tempest in 1944. Likely has something to do with fighting nazis.

Comment: @TrevorD: No, it's not US usage.  I'm a native US speaker born in the early 1980s, and the only times I can remember hearing the word *tempest* in everyday life are in the phrase *tempest in a teapot* and in reference to the Shakespeare play.  In fact, I wonder if Shakespeare is skewing the ngram data?

Answer (score 3):

The *OED* dates the first use of "thunder-storm" to around 1656, with the first cite for "thunderstorm" without the hyphen coming from Charles Darwin's 1839 *Voyage of the Beagle*. A Google Ngram [shows](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thunderstorm%2Ctempest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) usage of *tempest* undergoing a century-long downward slide before being eclipsed for good by *thunderstorm* in the late 1970s.

However, bear in mind that the word *tempest* is often (I would guess predominantly) used metaphorically in the modern era, whereas with *thunderstorm* the literal definition is pretty much all you get. *The Tempest* is also the title of a well-known Shakespeare play, which presumably inflates its usage quite a bit. So I would guess that the original use of *tempest* was probably supplanted by *thunderstorm* many decades before the 1970s.

Comment: I ask the question because my great-great grandmother, who lived in South Weymouth, Massachusetts, used the term frequently in her dairy of the year 1905.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to note about a thunderstorm is that it specifically implies thunder - as the word is in the name itself.  Whereas heavy wind and rain could be considered a tempest without thunder of any kind.

Though "tempest" is not very commonly used in casual conversation.  "Storm" would be acceptable, and does not specifically denote the presence of thunder.